False results for 6 decimals, good result for 18 decimals
===== 18 Decimals calculation
A total USD value of $28.18 in a token with 18 decimals.
Calculating a 1% fee on a total value of $28.18 USD gives a fee value of $0.2818 USD. Dividing this by the token price of $0.10 per token results in ~2.818 tokens required for the fee.
Smart contract reply: 2.81754 tokens = Correct.
===== 6 Decimals calculation
A total USD value of $6.93 in a token with 6 decimals.
Calculating a 1% fee on a total value of $6.93 USD gives a fee value of $0.0693 USD. Dividing this by the token price of $0.10 per token results in ~0.693 tokens required for the fee.
Smart contract reply: 0.00000000000069336 tokens = False.
== My solidity function:
    require(_index < lockedTokens[msg.sender].length, "Invalid index");

    LockedToken storage userToken = lockedTokens[msg.sender][_index];
    require(userToken.amount > 0, "No tokens to claim");

    uint256 amount = userToken.amount;
    address tokenAddress = userToken.tokenAddress;

    uint8 tokenDecimals = getTokenDecimals(tokenAddress);
    uint256 tokenPriceInUSD = getTokenPrice(tokenAddress);
    require(tokenPriceInUSD > 0, "Token price not available");

    uint256 nativeTokenPrice = getTokenPrice(allowedForcePay);
    require(nativeTokenPrice > 0, "Native token price not available");

    // Calculate fee
    uint256 totalClaimValueInUSD = (amount * tokenPriceInUSD) / (10 ** tokenDecimals);
    uint256 feeInUSD = (totalClaimValueInUSD * forcePayAmount) / 100;
    uint256 feeInNativeTokens = (feeInUSD * (10 ** 18)) / nativeTokenPrice;

    IERC20 forcePayToken = IERC20(allowedForcePay);
    require(forcePayToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, feeWallet, feeInNativeTokens), "Fee transfer failed");
    emit FeeTransferred(feeWallet, allowedForcePay, feeInNativeTokens, "force claim");

    lockedTokens[msg.sender][_index] = lockedTokens[msg.sender][lockedTokens[msg.sender].length - 1];
    lockedTokens[msg.sender].pop();

    require(IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, amount), "Transfer failed");

    claimedTokens[msg.sender].push(ClaimedToken({
        tokenAddress: tokenAddress,
        amount: amount,
        claimTime: block.timestamp
    }));

    emit TokensClaimed(msg.sender, tokenAddress, amount);
}

Part that calculates the values and fee:
uint256 totalClaimValueInUSD = (amount * tokenPriceInUSD) / (10 ** tokenDecimals);
    uint256 feeInUSD = (totalClaimValueInUSD * forcePayAmount) / 100;
    uint256 feeInNativeTokens = (feeInUSD * (10 ** 18)) / nativeTokenPrice;

Where do I go wrong that I get correct results for 18 decimals, but wrong results for 6 decimals.. is this due to the factor that I do not give attention to the decimals of the nativeTokenPrice? The decimals of the nativeTokenPrice are standard 18. Or is it the amount of tokens that need scaling as well?
Where do I go wrong in the calculations? I feel like I am at a dead end, and any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in Advance!
Edit: Token prices are stored by the way in a array in decimals, so for 6 decimals USDC for example: 999100n , 18 decimal token: 100000000000000000n , these get added to the array by javascript in a function call.

nativeTokenPrice is already in 18 decimals. Since the fee computation doesn’t account for the difference, precision errors occur.
The corrected code is
uint256 feeInNativeTokens = (feeInUSD * (10 ** 18)) / (nativeTokenPrice / (10 ** (18 - tokenDecimals)));
...whereby you are taking into consideration the difference in scaling between native token (10e18) and specific token (in this instance USDC w/ 10e6) decimal places.

You got it! I ran some tests, and it’s working exactly as it should now. Seems like I was pretty close, though haha , I had a feeling I was overlooking something. Thank you so much for pointing this out and providing the working snippet of code along with a detailed explanation.
